# Lucene Which would be better: many queries or massive OR query?

Tags: performance, search, lucene, lucene.net

Problem I have a large list of keywords that I want to see if the are contained in a document or documents. (My users want to know when a document is published, if it has any of their saved keywords)

- So I could make many queries; one for each keyword.
- Or I could construct a query something like: `"coffee OR tea OR milk OR sugar OR beer"`

Now lets say there are over 1,000 key words.

- Which one is likely to lead to pain and suffering?
- Would one be better over the other when running against one document or many documents?

(I am leaning towards the OR version but I am am worried I will hit some query length (performance) limit if I go too far)

---

Once I have enough data I will run some comparisons and report back.

Any hints between now and then would be great though.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [`MemoryIndex`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/memory/org/apache/lucene/index/memory/MemoryIndex.html) class for such tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single Giant Query Pro: You get ranking by the Lucene's scoring algorithm for all of the keywords.

Single Giant Query Con: You make Lucene use a huge amount of memory, as it needs to remember each subquery's result (or part of it) in order to give you that nice ranking that takes all keywords into account. The bigger the OR query, the more memory Lucene needs to do it, and the slower it does it.

I'd say, if at all possible for your purposes, break it up, since OR queries are The Devil (even though it's sometimes necessary to deal with them); but benchmark should be better than asking random people for opinions :P